# extract 1st line with specific pattern using regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a string

```
set text {show log

===============================================================================
Event Log 
===============================================================================
Description : Default System Log
Log contents  [size=500   next event=7  (not wrapped)]

6 2020/05/22 12:36:05.81 UTC CRITICAL: IOM #2001 Base IOM
"IOM:1>some text here routes "

5 2020/05/22 12:36:05.52 UTC CRITICAL: IOM #2001 Base IOM
"IOM:2>some other text routes "

4 2020/05/22 12:36:05.10 UTC MINOR: abc #2001 some text here also 222 def "

3 2020/05/22 12:36:05.09 UTC WARNING: abc #2011 some text here 111 ghj"

1 2020/05/22 12:35:47.60 UTC INDETERMINATE: ghe #2010 a,b, c="7" "
}
```

I want to extract the 1st line that starts with "IOM:" using **regexp in tcl** ie

```
IOM:1>some text here routes
```

But implementation doesn't work, Can someone help here?

```
regexp -nocase -lineanchor -- {^\s*(IOM:)\s*\s*(.*?)routes$} $line match tag value
```

Comment: One of the reasons you're having trouble: "routes" is not at the end of the line. You need `routes.*$` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
regexp -nocase -- {(?n)^"IOM:.*} $text match
regexp -nocase -line -- {^"IOM:.*} $text match
```

See the [Tcl demo](https://ideone.com/D6saiX)

**Details**

- `(?n)` - (same as `-line` option) newline sensitive mode ON so that `.` could not match line breaks  ( see [Tcl regex docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm): *If newline-sensitive matching is specified, `.` and bracket expressions using `^` will never match the newline character (so that matches will never cross newlines unless the RE explicitly arranges it) and `^` and `$` will match the empty string after and before a newline respectively, in addition to matching at beginning and end of string respectively*)
- `^` - start of a line
- `"IOM:` - `"IOM:` string
- `.*` - the rest of the line to its end.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Wiktor's great answer, you might want to iterate over the matches:

```
set re {^\s*"(IOM):(.*)routes.*$}

foreach {match tag value} [regexp -all -inline -nocase -line -- $re $text] {
    puts [list $tag $value]
}
```

```
IOM {1>some text here }
IOM {2>some other text }
```

I see that you have a non-greedy part in your regex. The Tcl regex engine is a bit weird compared to other languages: the **first quantifier** in the regex sets the greediness **for the whole regex**.

```
set re {^\s*(IOM:)\s*\s*(.*?)routes$}   ; # whole regex is greedy
set re {^\s*?(IOM:)\s*\s*(.*?)routes$}  ; # whole regex in non-greedy
# .........^^
```